# how to add custom listview in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, custom-adapter

I have successfully add List View in fragment but when I add custom List View it show error.

That's my Fragment Code

```
public class CustomList extends Fragment {

    ListView custom_list;
    ListAdapter adapter;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, null);

        return view;
    }




    @Override 
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState); 

    custom_list= (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        custom_list.setAdapter(new StringArrayAdapter(getActivity(),   "http://sweepstakes.vectis360.com/api/images/sweeps//280_4f6a306c94af679657ced7273b5ad4ea41.jpg","Get 40% Off on Trip to Turkey","2013-12-23 20:42:05","$23"));

    }

}
```

That's my StringArrayAdapter Code

```
public class StringArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Bitmap bmp=null;
    String[] image,name,create_date,retail_value;
    Context ctx;
    LayoutInflater myInflater;
    ImageView iv;
    Drawable drw;

    String i,n,d,v;

    public StringArrayAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, String img, String name, String             c_date,String value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        i = img;
        n = name;
        d = c_date;
        v = value;
        myInflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return image.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return name[arg0];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub




        if(convertView == null)
            convertView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_view, parent,false);


        try {
            drw = DownloadDrawable(image[position], "src");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        iv = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.entries_image);
        iv.setImageDrawable(drw);

        TextView tv1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.entries_name);
        tv1.setText(name[position]);

        TextView tv2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.entries_date);
        tv2.setText(create_date[position]);

        return convertView;
    }

    Drawable DownloadDrawable(String url, String src_name) throws java.io.IOException 
    {
        return Drawable.createFromStream(((java.io.InputStream) new java.net.URL(url).getContent()), src_name);
    }


}
```

Comment: What error you got? Post your stacktrace.

Comment: which error? post your logcat.

Comment: That's the error
http://prntscr.com/2ztwao

Answer (score 1):

Since you added the `ListView` to the `Fragment`, it belongs to the fragment view's hierarchy

Change

```
 custom_list= (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

with

```
 custom_list= (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way also

```
View rootView;
    ListView listView;
    MyAdapter mytripAdapter;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        context = getActivity();
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
        setData();
        return rootView;
    }




    private void setData(Data response) {
            listView = (ListView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.listView);


            mytripAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(),
                    pendingApprovalsList);
            listView.setAdapter(mytripAdapter);
    }
```